# Remove span if both first and second column empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got some JQuery that gets the first and second columns in a list and changes the height of an element depending on the max height between the two. This works great making sure the titles are of equal height however I'm trying to strip a span out if it is empty in either of the two columns. Here is my working script so far:

```
var $sections = $('.section-link'); //the column box
$sections.filter(function() {
return $(this).css('display') == 'block'; //aslong as the column box is visible
}, ':nth-child(2n-1)').each(function (index, value) { //get 1st to 2nd column boxs
    var $this = $(this);
    var $els = $this.nextAll(':lt(1)').addBack(); //get both
    var sectionheight = new Array(); //empty section height
    $els.each(function (index, value) {
        var value = $(this).find('.section-title').height();
        sectionheight.push(value);
        var value2 = $(this).find('.was-price-container'); //this is the span that I'm trying to hide
        if($.trim(value2.html()) != "") {
        //here we have identified the span is empty and now I need to find a way to hide it if not in either boxes in second of first column
        }
    });
    var newsectionheight = Math.max.apply(Math, sectionheight);
    $els.find('.section-title').height(newsectionheight);
});
```

This is working fine for height however I'm getting stuck identifying if this column's span `was-price-container` has contents, and if it does don't remove the span on this column or the previous or last column.

```
- title - | - title -
- span  - | - span  - < both columns have the span so keep it
----------------------
- title - | - title -
- span  - | -       - < only one column has the span so keep both
----------------------
- title - | - title - < neither have span so remove it
----------------------
- title - | - title -
-       - | - span  - < only one column has the span so keep both
----------------------
```

The reason for doing this is so that all boxes keep equal height.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this could be a solution for you. But couldn't you just use the :empty selector with jQuery to remove the empty span's.

```
$('span:empty').remove();
```

Or use it with a selector

```
$('.was-price-container span:empty').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, that would probably be much easier than my if statement, however the main problem is having it identify the column before or after deepening on if its the first or second, then removing the span only if both are empty.

Comment: Could you share the HMTL? Would be much easier to figure out how and when the elements should be handled.

Comment: See here for html: http://jsfiddle.net/2d8Tk/ the html is simple, its just 2 divs side by side in a list of about 10-20 divs.